# Properly placing an institution logo without messing the layout

Tags: graphics, templates, includegraphics, logos

I am writing my lab report in LaTeX with class `article` and I don't know how to properly put the university logo in the right side of the paper. As you see on the screenshot below, the logo creates additional blank spaces on the left.

[image: screenshot1]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=2cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{flushleft}
{\bf EEM 238 Digital Systems}\\
\par
First name \textsc{Surname}
\hfill \includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{logo.png}\\
\underline{ID Number:} 09XXXX76
\end{flushleft}

\begin{center}%\vspace{1cm}
\textbf{ \large Karnaugh tables}\\
Experiment 1
\end{center}

 \rule{\linewidth}{0.1mm}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\bigskip

\end{document}
```

I wish to obtain the kind of output below but I don't know how to properly put the logo there in the right side:

[image: screenshot2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several posibilities to get your wanted result.

One possibility is to use a `tabularx` environment. It creates a table, where we can write your text into the first column and keep the image/logo in the second column. With `multirow` we can build one cell going over two rows for the image.

Please see the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[%
  left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=2cm,a4paper,
  showframe % <================================== visualize typing area and margins
]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[t]{@{}Xr@{}} % <============================
  \textbf{EEM 238 Digital Systems} & \multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-duck}} \\
  \underline{ID Number:} 09XXXX76  & \\
\end{tabularx}

%\vspace{1cm}
\begin{center}
\textbf{\large Karnaugh tables}\\
Experiment 1
\end{center}

\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.1mm}


\bigskip

\end{document}
```

Please note that I added command `\noindent` to get rid of the leading space for table and rule. Now table and rule stayed inside the typing area, as you can see with option `showframe` for package `geometry`.

The result is:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: I am getting back on this old question and I would really love to know how to get rid of the "Overfull vbox" warnings.

Comment: thank you very much for replying. I am also using MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit on Windows and here is a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/shBt95X.png

Comment: As you instructed, I updated my MikTeX distribution and re-ran the compiling. Nonetheless, I still get the "Badbox" warning messages. Here is the screenshot using TexMaker in Windows: https://i.imgur.com/kWJsIaT.png. Then I tried using overleaf online and it returned the same warning message as well: https://i.imgur.com/3BQltZ8.png